# Using VSCode Find and Replace To Replace a String But Ignore Another String

Tags: visual-studio-code

so I have a lot of json files I want to edit with vscodes search and replace that have two similar lines of code as seen below.

what I want to do is replace the file extension .png only in the line that has "uri": in it and to ignore and not replace the .png in the "image": with the file extension .json

I'm assuming you would need to use RegEx in the search box but I'm not sure how.

```
"image": "https://bafybeifttigjlcslecb6mjch6c2un7xeiu3d5hxrslvt4eo6zknd3d5saa.ipfs.nftstorage.link/5024.png",
```

```
 "uri": "https://bafybeifdj22bwjzt7eahccynyyxsqeqnw6z4iaax7tyveh27j6cnjynvm4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/5024.png",
```

tried searching in vscode documentation but couldn't find a answer

Comment: so I want to replace all .png in the file but ignore the line that has "image"; in it essentially.

I hear regex isn't easily just learned and looking at the documentation is confusing.

Comment: replace `.png` to what? regex is very easy to learn, there are many websites with tutorials and what you need is the basics, there are also many regex play sites where you can see the immediate result